# WaveHC Library Trouble

Tags: sd-card, spi, adafruit

I posted this on the main Arduino forum, but no one has responded in 24 hours.

I'm trying to use the `WaveHC` library from Adafruit with a custom PCB. I am having trouble getting the `SPI` com to work for some reason, I modified the `ArduinoPins.h`, `SS_PIN`, from pin 10 to 8.

Using the Arduino SD library, I can see all the files no problem.

In the `WaveHC` library, all of the examples freeze after `card.init()`, I traced it to the `spiSend(uint8_t b)` in `SdReader.cpp`. It seems to get stuck in `while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF))`. This looks like the `SPDR` register (the `SPI` data register) is never loaded properly.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Adafruit library : https://github.com/adafruit/WaveHC

Edit :
This is the output from the SDReadTest example (Arduino SD Library)

```
Initializing SD card...Wiring is correct and a card is present.

Card type: SD2

Volume type is FAT32

Volume size (bytes): 1973350400
Volume size (Kbytes): 1927100
Volume size (Mbytes): 1881

Files found on the card (name, date and size in bytes): 
SYSTEM~1/     2016-11-07 14:11:06
  INDEXE~1      2016-11-07 14:11:06 76
0.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 22124
1.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 18604
2.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 19244
3.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 19884
4.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 21164
5.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 23084
6.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 21484
7.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 29484
8.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 20844
9.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 25004
P.WAV         2016-11-07 11:44:14 21804
```

Notes :

- I am using an Atmega328P @ 8MHz with the pro mini bootloader (this may be the issue)
- `SPI_DEFAULT_HALF_SPEED` is set to true
- `SPI_INIT_SLOW` is set to 1

Comment: Please post both code and circuit schematic.

Comment: I have tried all the examples in their repository https://github.com/adafruit/WaveHC. A schematic is unnecessary, I have verified my connections by testing my board with the arduino SD library.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to your Arduino forum post. Try setting the pinMode of SS pin of your microcontroller(10 on ATmega328P, 53 on ATmega2560) to OUTPUT in your setup() function. Even though you can use any pin to control the SS pin of the SD card, you need to sure the microcontroller's SS pin doesn't go low while using SPI, otherwise it goes into slave mode. Other useful information would be which microcontroller you're using and whether you've tried using the WaveHC library with SS on pin 10.

Comment: The arduino post is copy and paste...and still no one has responded. The pinMode for the SS pin is in the init method in SdReader.cpp, also I already tried adding in another pinMode in the setup. I'm using the Atmega328P 8Mhz. I can't try to use pin 10 because it is a smd custom PCB.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the WaveHC readme?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the suggestions in the readme

Comment: Just noticed that if the SS_PIN is left as 10 (as default, but not connected to anything in my case), I immediately get an error code, when I set it to 9 (not connected to anything either), it gets stuck in the while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) just like when it is set to 8 (which is the correct SS_PIN)

Comment: It seems that something is happening in the library that only allow SS to be 10, but I can't find where that is.. EDIT: Just thought that maybe there is a timing thing that depends on a 16Mhz clock

Comment: Just ran my board at 16MHz (@3.3V, don't yell at me, I know it's unstable) and it does the same thing, so I'm kind of ruling out the clock frequency being the issue.

Comment: Alrighty, found an SD breakout with a buffer and tested it with an Arduino Uno, and it works with pin 10 but not with pin 8 (whereas the official SD library works with both pins). So it looks like there is something in the library preventing the SS from being changed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I did not read this comment carefully

```
/** SPI slave select pin. Warning: SS may be redefined as another pin
but the hardware SS_PIN must be set to output mode before any calls to
WaveHC functions. The SS_PIN can then be used as a general output pin */
```

"SS_PIN must be set to output mode before any calls to
WaveHC functions"

I read this and thought that meant whatever pin was being used as the SS pin needed to be an output, but it meant literally that pin 10 (the hardware SS pin) had to be set as an output regardless of whether it was being used or not.

So the solution is to add

```
pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
```

to anywhere in the code

Edit : also thanks @per1234 for pointing out the correct answer, I just didn't read your comment properly.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution! Please update your post on the Arduino forum with a link to this page so that people there will know you no longer need assistance. This will also help anyone with the same problem who finds your post there to be led to the answer.